# Missing Text Editor setting in Fonts and Colors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am unable to change the fonts and colors for the text editor in Visual Studio 2013. I've repaired the installation and uninstalled and installed VS2013 again only to run into the same problem.

I'm attaching a picture of the issue. Any idea on how to fix it?

[image: Visual Studio Fonts and Colors Dialog]

Comment: Have you tried exporting your settings?  Something (eg. theme) may be incompatible.

Comment: The problem turned out to be with SQL Server 2014 Business Intelligence. I re-installed that and everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with SQL Server 2014 Business Intelligence. I re-installed that and everything worked.